# Google Sheets script - sort extremely slow

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have what I think is fairly straightforward/simple code in Google sheets to do some autosorting based on which file I'm in. The code *works*, but it takes up to *half a minute* to execute. Is there some way I can optimize this?

Here's the code:

```js
function autoSort(sheet) {
  var data = {};

  var sortMap = {
    "*** Artwork ***": {
      tableRange: "A5:R100",
      sortCriteria: [
        {column: 12, ascending: true},
        {column: 5, ascending: true}
      ]
    },
    "*** Artists ***": {
      tableRange: "A3:Z102",
      sortCriteria: [
        {column: 2, ascending: true}
      ]
    }
  };

  if (data = sortMap[sheet.getName()]) {
      sheet.getRange(data.tableRange).sort(data.sortCriteria);
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  autoSort(activeSheet);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing anything that involves large number of cells (like 100 * 25 in your example) with *every edit* to the sheet is going to be a major drag on performance. Google Sheets tend to queue up data operations to reduce their server load, so a good chunk of time is just spent waiting for green light. Google only offers so much computing power to Sheets/Script users.

The only optimization I can see here is to check whether the edit was made to the columns by which you sort.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = e.Range;
  if ([2, 5, 12].indexOf(activeRange.columnStart) != -1) {
    autosort(activeSheet);
  }
}
```

This won't help if the range you are sorting by is where all the editing takes place anyway.

The better way would be to give up the idea of things being sorted on edit, and offer the user a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_or_forms) for that purpose.